# Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::offset does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, eloquent

Hi i'm trying to paginate my view and i have this following code in my controller for the pagination:

```
    public function membrevis()
      {
      $filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : null;
      $query = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_role', 'users.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'user_role.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('users.valid','=',0)
        ->select('users.*','roles.description');
        if ($filter != null) {
        $query->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
            ->orWhere('roles.description','like','%'.$filter.'%');
        }
     $users = $query->get();


    $itemsPerPage = 8 ;
    $currentPage  = isset( $_GET['page'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $urlPattern   = '/profilecontroller/membrevis?page=(:num)';
    $totalItems   = $users->count();
    $donner   = $users->offset( ( $currentPage - 1 ) * $itemsPerPage )->limit( $itemsPerPage )->get();
    $paginator = new  Paginator( $totalItems, $itemsPerPage, $currentPage, $urlPattern );

return view('membre2',['users'=> $donner,'paginator'=> $paginator]);
```

My view membre2.blade.php has the following code as well for pagination:

```
  <form>
 ....
  </form>
 <table>
@foreach($users as $row)
....
@endforeach
 </table>
echo $paginator;
```

But i' still get this error **Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::offset does not exist.** knowing i already installed "jasongrimes/paginator:~1.0" by CMD

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is `$users` query in your controller? show your code completely.

Comment: Laravel 4 or Laravel 5, pick one.

Comment: before  **$donner**  code what is dd(get_class($user)) it is printed **Illuminate\Support\Collection**;

Comment: May be offset value set to 0

Comment: @MehdiAlipour I just update my post with the full code of my controller profilecontroller.php

Comment: Hi @Davit it returns : "Illuminate\Support\Collection"

Comment: @Kyslik I'm sorry I 'm working basically on Laravel 5 but i think this has nothing to do with which version of Laravel

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Illuminate\Support\Collection::offset does not exist.** it is because your **$users** is instance of  **Illuminate\Support\Collection**. For check it use **dd(get_class($users));** after **$totalItems = $users->count();** It must be print **Illuminate\Support\Collection**. Collection instance has count method, which return *Collection items count*. For your **$users->offset( ( $currentPage - 1 ) * $itemsPerPage )->limit( $itemsPerPage )->get()** code work right you must be change **$users to $query(maybe $users)**  where **$query(maybe $users)** isntance of **\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder**.
For this case use

```
$query->->offset( ( $currentPage - 1 ) * $itemsPerPage )->limit( $itemsPerPage )->get();
```

Your corrected code is

```
public function membrevis()
{
    $filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : null;
    $query = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_role', 'users.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'user_role.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('users.valid','=',0)
        ->select('users.*','roles.description');
    if ($filter != null) {
        $query->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
            ->orWhere('roles.description','like','%'.$filter.'%');
    }

    $itemsPerPage = 8 ;
    $currentPage  = isset( $_GET['page'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $urlPattern   = '/profilecontroller/membrevis?page=(:num)';
    $totalItems   = $query->count();
    $donner   = $query->offset( ( $currentPage - 1 ) * $itemsPerPage )->limit( $itemsPerPage )->get();
    $paginator = new  Paginator( $totalItems, $itemsPerPage, $currentPage, $urlPattern );

    return view('membre2',['users'=> $donner,'paginator'=> $paginator]);
}
```

I delete $users = $query->get() method which is one more request in db. And for get total user count you used *$totalItems   = $query->count();* which is more optimized query

Comment: So you think my code should change to:  ** $donner   =  $query->get()->offset( ( $currentPage - 1 ) * $itemsPerPage )->limit( $itemsPerPage )->get();** ??

Comment: when you use  $query->get() it return instance of **Illuminate\Support\Collection** class. the **->get()** method must be used the end of query

Comment: Hi that error is finally gone! Thank you man! But there is still one problem the echo $paginator; call in my view doesn't eem to work, it is shown as it is in my view and doesnt return the pagination! do you know hwo to fix this?

Comment: I dont used **Paginator** class. in this case i can not help you.

Comment: see official documentation [https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html) it must be helpful for you